# Stored procedure not giving the results of multiple out parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm not good in writing stored procedures. Please help me on this. I use mysql workbench. I created stored procedure to get two outputs with two select statements. But it gives only the out put of one select statement which is written last in the stored procedure. Following is the procedure.

```
  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`(IN date_x DATE,   OUT emplist3 varchar(200), OUT emplist4 varchar(200))
  BEGIN
  select employee.name as emplist3
  from employee
  where employee.id IN (
    select emp_position.employee_id
    from emp_position
    where emp_position.employee_id NOT IN (
       select emp_event.employee_id
       from emp_event
       where emp_event.date = date_x
    )
    AND emp_position.position = "Cameraman"
   );

  select employee.name as emplist4
  from employee
  where employee.id IN (
     select emp_position.employee_id
     from emp_position
     where emp_position.employee_id NOT IN (
        select emp_event.employee_id
        from emp_event
        where emp_event.date = date_x
     )
     AND emp_position.position = "Camera_Assistant"
     );
    END
```

Please help me to get the result of both emplist3 and emplist4 from the above procedure.
Thank U.

Comment: you should use inner join instead of in and left join instead of not in to get better performance ,better sql query

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal  I'm not good in writing this database stuff.  Could u please edit my code with your solution?

Comment: The procedure you have published looks like it should work. Can you edit your question to include the code which calls it (including the variable definitions) , the actual output from the code and confirmation that the select statements work as expected when run in mysqlworkbench.  If you can publish sample data that would be good,

Comment: You need to do select into, Check my answer and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Adjust and modify the following example according to your need.

```sql
mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `new_procedure`//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`(
    ->   IN `date_x` DATE,
    ->   OUT `emplist3` VARCHAR(200),
    ->   OUT `emplist4` VARCHAR(200)
    -> )
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SELECT 'EMPLOYEE.NAME 1' INTO `emplist3`
    ->   FROM DUAL
    ->   WHERE `date_x` = `date_x`;
    -> 
    ->   SELECT 'EMPLOYEE.NAME 2' INTO `emplist4`
    ->   FROM DUAL
    ->   WHERE `date_x` = `date_x`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> SET @`NAME1` := NULL,
    ->     @`NAME2` := NULL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL `new_procedure`(DATE('2000-01-01'), @`NAME1`, @`NAME2`);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @`NAME1`, @`NAME2`;
+-----------------+-----------------+
| @`NAME1`        | @`NAME2`        |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| EMPLOYEE.NAME 1 | EMPLOYEE.NAME 2 |
+-----------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Select into the two parameters because that is what an out parameter is there for.

You also need to make sure that the return values are scalar,

You cannot return a whole resultset in an out parameter.

The main benefit to using output parameters is that you can do some manipulation to the data inside the procedure before returning it,
If you do not have any intention of doing that and/or you might return multiple rows then you cant really use out parameters.

Also you have not changed the delimiter in your code, you need to change the delimiter inside a stored procedure so MYSQL treats the whole procedure as a block of code.

try this:
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE new_procedure(date_x DATE,OUT emplist3 varchar(200),
OUT emplist4 varchar(200)
)

```
BEGIN
      select employee.name INTO emplist3
      from employee
      where employee.id IN (
          select emp_position.employee_id
          from emp_position
          where emp_position.employee_id NOT IN (
              select emp_event.employee_id
              from emp_event
              where emp_event.date = date_x
          )
      AND emp_position.position = "Cameraman"
      );

     select employee.name INTO emplist4
     from employee
     where employee.id IN (
         select emp_position.employee_id
         from emp_position
         where emp_position.employee_id NOT IN (
             select emp_event.employee_id
             from emp_event
             where emp_event.date = date_x
         )
     AND emp_position.position = "Camera_Assistant"
     );
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

After creating the procedure you need to call a select statement on the parameters like so:

```
SELECT @emplist3,@emplist4;
```

Or if you are calling the procedure later:

```
CALL new_procedure(@myout1,@myout2);
SELECT @myout1,@myout2;
```